# How to respect Content Security Policy when using JQuery UI dialog Widget?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, dialog, content-security-policy, inline-styles

I'm setting up CSP directives on an existing project that uses the JQuery UI dialog widget (https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).
Using CSP, I do not want to allow the use of inline style.

Unfortunately, when the dialog function is called, JQuery UI automatically applies inline style to some dialog elements.

I know that is possible to overwrite and clear the style attribute after the elements have been loaded,  but this possible fix does not prevent the CSP warnings.

Is there a way to call the dialog function completely avoiding the generation of inline style directives?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Essentially, no, not out of the box. You can use the `$.widget()` to mutate a copy of Dialog such that it no longer writes inline style. If you leverage any of the other widgets, like Drag or Resize, with Dialog, they *always* use inline styles that cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery UI doesn't use the crude `element.innerHTML = "<tag style = 'inline_styles_here'>"` method, but uses the `attr()` function, that is [jQuery-csp-inline-style-fix](https://github.com/jonathanKingston/jQuery-csp-inline-style-fix).

Also there is a [hack for setAttribute()](https://csplite.com/csp/test343/) function, it covers both jQuery and pure JavaScript.